# Sending json array to rest endpoint results in jackson parsing exception

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

**My used stack**

- spring boot 1.5.6 realease
- ajax  jquery  3.3.1

**My objective**

I m trying to print some data into jasper report so I created a rest controller, I got the idea to send json data from front end and got it parsed thanks to jackson api into List of pojo then using the JRDataBean to process my report

**My code**

When pushing the print button I m sending this json array using ajax that I got from the chrome console by making it a global variable then using a copy ( atrick that I googled to get variable content as string )

- here is my json

.

```
   [ {
    "codeInterne": 45,
    "clientName": "TalcorpDZ",
    "clientPhone": "+213778217469",
    "codeExterne": "CLI201801",
    "email": "talcorpdz@gmail.com",
    "clientType": 0,
    "clientEtat": 1,
    "identifiant": "TalcorpDZ",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "nom": "Taleb",
        "prenom": "Mohammed Housseyn",
        "telephonePortable": "04330256699",
        "email": null
      }
    ],
    "adresses": [
      {
        "adress": "Batiments des enseignants Mohammed Khemisti",
        "ville": "Maghnia"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "codeInterne": 64,
    "clientName": "lkjhgf",
    "clientPhone": "+213778217469",
    "codeExterne": "dfghjk",
    "email": "talcorpdz@gmail.com",
    "clientType": 1,
    "clientEtat": 1,
    "identifiant": "lkjhgf",
    "contacts": [
      {
        "nom": "Taleb",
        "prenom": "Mohammed",
        "telephonePortable": "02354649",
        "email": "talcorpdz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "adresses": [
      {
        "adress": "Batiments des enseignants Mohammed Khemist",
        "ville": "Maghnia"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- and here is the part where I do the post request

.

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu0-func1-menu0-func1', function(){
        console.log(printData);
            var settings = {
                "async" : true,
                "crossDomain" : true,
                "url" : "http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/print/client",
                "method" : "POST",
                "headers" : {
                    "cache-control" : "no-cache",
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                "processData" : false,
                "contentType" : "application/json",
                "dataType" : "json",
                "data" : printData
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);

            });
    });
```

the post is well received by my controller which is coded as the following :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PrintController.API)
public class PrintController {
    public static final String API="print";


    @PostMapping("client")
    public void export(@RequestBody List<ClientJsonDto> datas,HttpServletResponse response){

        System.out.println(datas);

        // processing the print mechanisme

    }
}
```

finally here is my ClientJsonDto.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "codeInterne",
    "clientName",
    "clientPhone",
    "codeExterne",
    "email",
    "clientType",
    "clientEtat",
    "identifiant",
    "contacts",
    "adresses"
})
public class ClientJsonDto {

    @JsonProperty("codeInterne")
    private Integer codeInterne;
    @JsonProperty("clientName")
    private String clientName;
    @JsonProperty("clientPhone")
    private String clientPhone;
    @JsonProperty("codeExterne")
    private String codeExterne;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty("clientType")
    private Integer clientType;
    @JsonProperty("clientEtat")
    private Integer clientEtat;
    @JsonProperty("identifiant")
    private String identifiant;
    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    private List<Contact> contacts = null;
    @JsonProperty("adresses")
    private List<Adress> adresses = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// getters, setters 
}
```

adress.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "adress",
    "ville"
})
public class Adress {

    @JsonProperty("adress")
    private String adress;
    @JsonProperty("ville")
    private String ville;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//getters, setters
}
```

contact.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "nom",
    "prenom",
    "telephonePortable",
    "email"
})
public class Contact {

    @JsonProperty("nom")
    private String nom;
    @JsonProperty("prenom")
    private String prenom;
    @JsonProperty("telephonePortable")
    private String telephonePortable;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 //getters setters
}
```

the exception that I m facing is:

> 2018-11-18 15:12:40.255  WARN 1768 --- [nio-8082-exec-9]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting ('true',
>   'false' or 'null'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'object': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@1df244f9; line: 1, column: 9]

what can I do to see what my rest controller is receiving as request body before that jackson tries to marshal?

what can I do to fix this exception?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion it was instructive, I fixed the bug here is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json value and mapping is all correct but i can't see producer and consumer with post mapping request as you have to explicitly define the producer and consumer.

The error could be due to the format of data you are giving to your controller. Your controller method is expecting JSON string. For example in case of jQuery, JSON.stringify() gives you JSON string. So I would suggest you confirm this at the client side from where you're sending the data to this controller.

Code which you need to change and check.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PrintController.API)
public class PrintController {
    public static final String API="print";

@PostMapping("client",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void export(@RequestBody List<ClientJsonDto> datas,HttpServletResponse response){

            System.out.println(datas);

            // processing the print mechanisme

        }
    }
```

Comment: After a day of searching I believe that I m doing things wrong in my js I will try to refactor all my js code and keep you in touch

Comment: can you try to use private List<Contact> contacts; instead of assigning null value also for private List<Adress> adresses; as well.

Comment: thanks to you talking about json string I figured it out so I accept also your answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to see what is being received so that you can find why it is not getting mapped to your DTO.

Try changing

```
@RequestBody List<ClientJsonDto> datas
```

to

```
@RequestBody List<Map> datas
```

or

```
@RequestBody List datas
```

And see if you can print and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got fixed

I based my fix upon this [tutorial](https://grokonez.com/frontend/jquery/ajax-jquery-post-list-javascript-objects-springboot-server-bootstrap),what I mentioned is I m handling my array in a shady way so I tried the same principle, and I added the JSON.stringify and changed the datatype to text

here is all the changes that I made

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu0-func1-menu0-func1', function(){
    console.log(printData);
    var jsonData =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(printData));
        var settings = {
            "async" : true,
            "crossDomain" : true,
            "url" : "http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/print/client",
            "method" : "POST",
            "headers" : {
                "cache-control" : "no-cache",
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            "processData" : false,
            "contentType" : "application/json",
            "dataType" : "text",
            "data" : JSON.stringify(printData)
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

        });
});
```

the print data that I m printing is handled as below

```
var printData =[];

function displayList(){
    console.log("click");
    if(console.log($('#search-client').val())){
        console.log($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase());
    }
    var as=clientsData.filter((n,i,a) =>{return (
            n.email.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.contacts[0].nom.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
            n.contacts[0].prenom.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.adresses[0].ville.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.contacts[0].telephonePortable.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0)});
    var html=' ';
    console.log(as.length);
    printData = [];
    for(var i=0; i<as.length ; i++){
        var ClientJsonDto = as[i];
        html+=[{client : as[i] , index : i}].map(RefCliElement).join('');   
        printData.push(ClientJsonDto);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(printData));
    $('#clientList').html(html);
    console.log(html);

}
```

before the fix it was like this, may be this idea is to avoid because I was using a jquery array of objects whithout knowing

```
var printData;

function displayList(){
    console.log("click");
    if(console.log($('#search-client').val())){
        console.log($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase());
    }
    var as=clientsData.filter((n,i,a) =>{return (
            n.email.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.contacts[0].nom.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
            n.contacts[0].prenom.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.adresses[0].ville.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0 || 
            n.contacts[0].telephonePortable.toLowerCase().indexOf($('#search-client').val().toLowerCase()) >= 0)});
    var html=' ';
    console.log(as.length);
    for(var i=0; i<as.length ; i++){
        html+=[{client : as[i] , index : i}].map(RefCliElement).join('');   
    }
    printData = as;
    $('#clientList').html(html);
    console.log(html);

}
```

wish this helps entry level like me in the futur